Camera is black on Acer laptop
I have an Acer laptop that uses Windows 11 and has a built-in webcam. I can turn the camera on with the camera app. The green light lights up and I get a popup on my screen that says "camera on" but all I see is a black screen. The camera is not covered up by anything and there is no button on my keyboard to enable/disable the camera (as far as I can tell). I've tried many solutions, followed a few youtube tech help videos, and even tried all the steps in this Microsoft Community post. Nothing seems to work and I still only have a black screen for my camera. A few of the thing I tried were checking for updates (both driver updates for the camera and Windows updates), disabling and re-enabling my camera in the device manager, and completely removing the device to download the latest driver. I've restarted after trying each solution and nothing has worked so far. Can anyone help me fix this issue?


Is there a hidden sliding cover for the webcam? 2. Try an external webcam to test if the internal camera has issues.


As above. Also check the product's page for vendor's (not Microsoft's) specific drivers. Of course, if your laptop didn't come with Windows 11 or Windows 11 isn't supported by the vendor (ACER) you may find that a few devices just don't work.

Please [edit] the question and post the exact model.
